# Node.js rendering variables in Jade

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I want to view all the URL's in my view, but I get `#{data.id} Cannot read property 'id' of undefined` error.

I want to create a loop and view all the videos I have.

app.js

```
app.get('/you', function(req,res) {
    youtube.where('id', '<', '5689').fetchAll().then(function(data) {
        res.render('youtube', {
            mi : data
        });
    });
});
```

Here's an example output for a given ID (I changed res.render to res.send to test my query, so it works)

```
[
    {
        "id": 442,
        "channel_name": "channelNameredacted",
        "video_url": "videoURlRedacted",
        "video_title": "redacted",
        "status": 1,
        "date": "redacted"
    }
]
```

youtube.jade

Let's say I want to output video ID's.

```
html
  head
  body
    each data in mi
      #{data.id}
```

Comment: The only way I can see this error occurring with that view is if the `data` provided by `youtube` includes an `undefined` element in the collection – `[ { id: 442 }, undefined ]`. If you add the condition `if data` under the `each`, does it succeed then?

Comment: Side-note: Using `#{...}` at the start of a line renders a dynamically-named element – `<442></442>`. I'm guessing that's probably not what you were going for. To render `data.id` as text, add an element or [a pipe](http://jade-lang.com/reference/plain-text/) before it – `div #{data.id}` or `| #{data.id}`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, that was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it like this.

```
app.get('/ind', function(req,res) {
    youtube.where('id', '<', '100').fetchAll().then(function(data) {
        data = data.toJSON();
        res.render('youtube', {
            mi : data
        });
    });
});
```

youtube.jade

```
html
  head
  body
    ul
      for m in mi
        li #{m.id}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me -

```
var jade = require('jade'),
  fs = require('fs');

var data = {
  mi: [
    {
      "id": 442,
      "channel_name": "channelNameredacted",
      "video_url": "videoURlRedacted",
      "video_title": "redacted",
      "status": 1,
      "date": "redacted"
    }
  ]
};

fs.readFile('youtube.jade', 'utf-8', function(error, source){
  var html = jade.render(source, data);
  console.log(html)
});
```

youtube.jade

```
html
  head
  body
    ul
      each data in mi
        li= data.id
```

output

```
<html><head></head><body><ul><li>442</li></ul></body></html>
```